# Replacing a ceiling fan (with a pull chain light) with a 6 bulb chandelier

Tags: light-fixture

Once connected the lights will not turn on or off with the wall switch. In fact, the chandelier stays on regardless. Please help.

Comment: We need a lot more info.  We need to know how the wires were connected (pictures for preference), whether there's 1 or 2 (or more) switches, and possibly more.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have any pictures. There is one wall switch. To control the ceiling fan with pull chain light, the wall switch was turned on and then you could turn the light on/off with the pull chain. Also, the speed of the ceiling fan could be controlled by its pull chain. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You hooked the new light up to the 'always-hot' wire (probably red) which ran the ceiling fan.
Use the other 'switched-hot' wire (probably black) instead.

Comment: I checked to wires used for the ceiling fan and there are only 3 wires - black, white, and copper (ground). Which wire do I connect to?

Comment: What is the bulb type is in this fixture? ordinary screw base?

Answer (score 0):

What is the bulb type is in this fixture? ordinary screw base? What s the type 
of wire in the fixture which connects in the box? Is it lamp cord with one smooth wire and one ribbed or otherwise marked? If so, the smooth wire is to be connected to the switched hot, and the ribbed wire is to be connected to the neutral.

If the lights stay on, then you must examine the connections in the switch box. The switch is supposed to have a line hot on one side (black) and the switched hot (black) on the other. The incoming white (neutral) should be connected to the white (neutral) going to the ceiling box.